# Thread#wait() in Thread#run() and Thread#notify() from JFrame#keyPressed() - is my implementation Thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, keylistener

Sorry if what I'm posting contains compilation errors I have no IDE x compiler at the moment, so let's say we have two classes, a Battle one extending Thread and a Frame one extending JFrame and implementing KeyListener, plus a Main one to test those.

Battle.java:

```
public class Battle extends Thread{

    public synchronized void produce(){

        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}

    }

    public synchronized void consume(){

        notify();

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        int turn = 0;
        while(true){ //Just for testing
            System.out.println("[BATTLE]: Starting turn " + turn + "!");
            System.out.println("[BATTLE]: Doing stuff!");
            System.out.println("[BATTLE]: Waiting for user to press a key...");
            produce();
            System.out.println("[BATTLE]: Doing stuff!");
            System.out.println("[BATTLE]: Ending turn " + turn + "!");
            turn++;
        }

    }

}
```

Frame.java:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    private Battle battle;

    public Frame(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Threads");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        battle = new Battle();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
        battle.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        if(battle.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING){
            System.out.println("[LISTENER]: Key <" + e.getKeyChar() + "> pressed.");
            System.out.println("[LISTENER]: Going back to battle execution.");
            battle.consume();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Frame();

    }

}
```

You can replace both `sysout("Doing stuff!")` by actions like determine AI action before you choose yours pressing the key, and after player + AI chose their action, use it on each other and do all end-of-turn things.

Also I have to say I know for a fact that I will ever have 1..1 `Frame` object and 0..1 `Battle` object active at the same time.

So. I have a bunch of questions about what I've written.

Question1: As I'm very new to Threads in general, and **I'd like to know first if my `keyPressed`'s condition is well-written or not** (I'm not sure I've understood the differences between `Thread.State.WAITING` and `Thread.State.BLOCKED`)**?** **More generally, will my code always do the same thing, and does it really work the way I think it does** (via the input)**?**

Question2: Just by curiosity, in Frame's constructor, **if I reverse `battle = new Battle();` and `addKeyListener(this);`, shall I then change my `keyPressed`'s condition into `battle != null && battle.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING` in case I press a key fast enough to fire the event before `battle = new Battle()` is executed?**

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Still asking for help. :) Also I tested it on Eclipse and it *seemed* to work just fine.

Comment: Please if someone sees this, help me please. :)

Comment: Hey I'm not sure about the answer to your questions, but you could get an answer faster if you answered a few questions on Stack Overflow, gained some reputation points, and then put a +50 bounty on this question so more people will see it easier.